# Serilog not logging anything

Tags: c#, serilog

I'd like to use Serilog for my project, but I can't quite get it to work properly.

Right now, this is what I've got, just for verifying and testing purposes:

```
public MainLogger([NotNull] ILogPathProvider logPathProvider)
{
    m_logger = Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .CreateLogger();

    m_logger.Warning("blabla");
}
```

As you can see, there is not a lot going on besides just opening a log and trying to write a warning.

However, this warning does not appear.

Is there anything I forgot to configure / call?

Comment: What kind of application is it? I.e. ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core (hosting model option?), Windows Service, etc. - console output may end up in a different place depending on which of these is used. HTH! :-)

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt It's a service fabric application, the logging currently takes place only on background workers :)

Comment: Do you see any output calling `Console.WriteLine("Hello")`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed the correct NuGet Packages ([`Serilog`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog/) and [`Serilog.Sinks.Console`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Console/3.1.2-dev-00823)), then your code sample should print a Warning message in the console without requiring any changes.

You can confirm this by creating a simple Console application, installing the packages above, and running the same code.

The problem is elsewhere in your application and/or environment... It has nothing to do with Serilog.

Most likely, your method `MainLogger` is **not** being called at all, or perhaps your Console output is being redirected to somewhere else.

Comment: I just set a breakpoint to confirm, that the code is actually being run. I also added a test file output so I can be sure about the correct logging destination, but no luck with that as well

Comment: @Sossenbinder Again: The problem is elsewhere in your environment... Not with Serilog. Maybe the Console output being redirected, or something else. Create an empty Console App with Serilog and test it for yourself...